# What happens if Hebrew Slave goes on strike?

Tags: halacha-theory, slave-serve-eved-avadim

[@Joel's answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/99189/15579) to my previous question ["whats-so-slave-ish-in-the-hebrew-slave"](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/99184/whats-so-slave-ish-in-the-hebrew-slave) showed a possible difference between a slave and an employee - the later can simply walk away.

That made me think: what if a Hebrew slave decide to end his slavery (*is it parallel to a woman wanting a divorce?*), both if he sold himself or the court sold him?

Hebrew Slave is a Jew and all laws of נזקים apply to him so his master is forbidden to raise his hand upon him. As their relations are exclusively monetary, his master is very limited. Just like my boss at work.

- What would happen if he goes on strike and refuses to serve? As his body does not belong to his master the later can't harm him physically. Can a Beis Din?
- Is there a condition (similar to אישה מורדת) that would obligate the master to release him? What happens to the debt?

*(Should I break it into multiple questions?)*

Comment: He gets beaten, which is why we have rules governing what happens when his master beats him

Comment: @JoshK I suspect you're wrong. He's a Jew and all laws of נזקים apply to him so his master is forbidden to raise his hand upon a Hebrew Slave. As their relations are exclusively monetary, his master is very limited. Just like your boss at work.